# ReferenceError: myfunction is not defined

Tags: javascript

I have a `quickView()` function. when I click on it I get this error message:

```
ReferenceError: quickView is not defined
```

---

```
<a class="btn btn-sm popup-text" href="#product-quick-view-add-to-cart" onClick="quickView();" data-effect="mfp-move-from-top" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="add to cart">cart<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>
.
.
.
.
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function quickView(){
            console.log("test1");

            $.post({{base_url()}}'cart/getPopUpContent', {id:16169} , function(data){
                $('#product-quick-view-add-to-cart').html(data);
                console.log("test2");
            });
        }


    </script>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: post your full code.

Comment: Could not reproduce: https://jsfiddle.net/p3as2ogm/ Please post enough code to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @SkyWalker That is incorrect. It can be in the body.

Comment: It should work can you share some link/ more detail about this code

Comment: Your code is working on my side just add in proper html file (inside the body tag)

Comment: So what is happening exactly in your code that causes the issue. Is something being loaded dynamically?

Comment: my question is updated. when I delete `$.post(...` it works fine .

Comment: And there is your bug... POST all the code in the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your console when the page loads, you have a JavaScript error

```
$.post({{base_url()}}'cart/get', {id:16169} , function(data){
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Looks like you are using some sort of templating

When that will render it will be

```
$.post(foo/bar/'cart/get', {id:16169} , function(data){
```

You should notice the quotes are wrong. So move the opening quote in front of the base url part.

```
$.post('{{base_url()}}cart/get', {id:16169} , function(data){
      ^^^
```